# jasmine.js expect() does not work inside an asynchronous callback

Tags: javascript, ajax, bdd, jasmine

I'm getting acquainted with Jasmine (http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) and found something rather baffling:

```
it("should be able to send a Ghost Request", function() {
  var api = fm.api_wrapper;

  api.sendGhostRequest(function(response) {
    console.dir('server says: ', response);
  });

  expect(true).toEqual(false);
});
```

Fails as expected.

However, moving the expect call inside the callback:

```
it("should be able to send a Ghost Request", function() {
  var api = fm.api_wrapper;

  api.sendGhostRequest(function(response) {
    console.dir('server says: ', response);
    expect(true).toEqual(false);
  });
});
```

Somehow passes :O

After some debugging:
api.sendGhostRequest() does an asynchronous ajax request, and jasmine rushes past before the request has completed.

Hence the question:

How do I get jasmine to wait for ajax execution before ascertaining the test result?

Comment: With Jasmine 2.0 you just call it("desc",function(done){... done(); ...}). Just saying, because this thread is high in google results :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Edit for Jasmine 2**

Asynchronous tests have become much simpler in Jasmine 2. Any test that needs to handle asynchronous code can be written with a callback which will indicate the completion of the test. See the [Jasmine 2 docs](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support) under the header *Asynchronous Support*

```
it('should be able to send a ghost request', (done) => {
    api.sendGhostRequest((response) => {
        console.log(`Server says ${response}`);
        expect(true).toEqual(false);
        done();
    });
});
```

**Jasmine 1**

Have a look at **waitsFor()** and **runs()** on the [Jasmine site](http://jasmine.github.io/1.3/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support) under the header *Asynchronous Support*.

Use of runs and waitsfor should force Jasmine to wait for the ajax call to finish or for some timeout.

The code would look like:

```
it("should be able to send a Ghost Request", function() {
    runs(function() {
        api.sendGhostRequest(function(response) {
            console.dir('server says: ', response);
            flag = true;
        });
    }, 500);

    waitsFor(function() {
        return flag;
    }, "Flag should be set", 750);

    runs(function() {
        expect(true).toEqual(false);
    });
}
```

In which case the expect would fail.

Comment: Cheers! Feel embarrassed, like I've just been RTFM-ed :) Works like a charm :)

Comment: What is the '500' at the end of the first runs()?

Comment: The 500 on the first runs is a timeout for the asynchronous action. Alternatively you could add a setTimeout after the api.sendGhostRequest call to provide an alternate case to execute on timeout. For example:
    setTimeout(function() {
        flag = true;
    }, 500);

Comment: broken link. moved here: http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support

Comment: Jasmine 2 seems to have removed "waitsFor", and it's not at all clear to me what should be used instead :-( . It might be worth updating your answer with "Jasmine 1" and "Jasmine 2" sections, if you know the new approach?

Answer (score 4):

As @pkopac commented, `runs()` and `waitsFor()` have been deprecated in v2 favour of using a `done()` callback as documented: https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support

```
it("should be able to send a Ghost Request", function(done) {
    var api = fm.api_wrapper;

    var success = function(response) {
        console.dir('server says: ', response);
        expect(response).toEqual('test response')
        done();
    };

    api.sendGhostRequest(success);
});
```

Comment: `done` should be in function parameter to use. `it("should be able to send a Ghost Request", function(done) {`

Comment: How do you wait for a condition to become true in the spec? i.e. what do I do if I want to wait for my app to work, but I don't have a "success" callback? Do I need to write my own "waitFor" polling loop?

Answer (score 1):

Look into runs() and waitfor()

Specifically you can call waitfor to check that the callback has run in some fashion (maybe using a boolean as a check?)  and then run the expect afterwards.

runs allows you to wait until the waitfor has completed.

[async jasmine documentation](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Asynchronous-specs)