# jasmine test run even before .click() is triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I am just playing with a basic ruby application which changes the html direction attribute upon clicking an button. Its working fine on the JQuery side but in my test case runs even when .click() is triggers. Here are my files.

display.html.erb

```
<p>
<%= button_tag 'Convert', id: 'test', remote: 'true' %>
</p>
```

Jquery: conversion.js

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#test').on('click', setHtmlStyle);
});
var setHtmlStyle = function(){
var $style = $('html');
$style.attr('dir', $style.attr('dir') === 'rtl' ? 'ltr' : 'rtl');
};
```

Spec: conversion_spec.js

```js
describe('#test', function (){
  beforeEach(function(){
    loadFixtures('conversion.html');
  });
  describe('Clicking test button', function(){
    it('should have an attribute', function(){
      $('#test').click();
      expect($('html').attr('dir')).toBe('rtl');
    });
  });
```

Fixture: conversion.html

```
<html>
<input type='button' name='Convert' id='test'>
</html>
```

Here is the error message when i run my tests:

```
Failure/Error: Expected 'ltr' to be 'rtl'.
```

Any help or suggestions would be truly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: the input `id='rtl'` should be `id='test'` right ?

Comment: Yup, edited it for my question. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know Jasmine very well. But have you tried to do an "async expect" ?

Comment: I just began working with jasmine. I am not sure what `async expect` would do. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: there is an example in the accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141834/jasmine-js-expect-does-not-work-inside-an-asynchronous-callback

Comment: @JoãoMosmann Tried using an example from http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support but still haven't solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had changed my code in order to make sure the .click() function is working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '#test', setHtmlStyle);
});

var setHtmlStyle = function(){
  var $style = $('html');
  $style.attr('dir', $style.attr('dir') === 'rtl' ? 'ltr' : 'rtl');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that attr('dir') is not defined, its value is 'undefined', if you set explicitely set the tag attribute to 'rlt' or 'ltr' it will have a string value you have set it.

`$style.attr('dir', $style.attr('dir') === 'rtl' && typeof $style.attr('dir') !== "undefined" ? 'ltr' : 'rtl');`

undefined

Comment: It still doesn't solve my issue. I changed the script and ran my test but still shows the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code and got it working with the following simple modification (in addition to implementing a quick-workaround for the jasmine-jquery-rails gem to loading fixtures):

```
$('#test').click();
```

is changed to

```
setHtmlStyle();
```

This got the test working correctly.

Jasmine is a unit-testing tool for low-level JavaScript code, with DOM elements hidden from view during execution. So, doing a `click()` with jQuery has no effect.

What that means is unlike Selenium or Capybara, Jasmine's goal is to help developer with testing/test-driving low-level JavaScript logic units, such as calculations, and some light-weight DOM manipulation.

The quick take-away from that is you write your tests against the low-level JavaScript methods that get the work done for user interactions, but not for methods that involve click() and such. This helps you have a quick feedback loop on testing small functionality. In other words, it's concerned with the "in" phase of outside-in BDD testing.

The "out" phase must be tackled with integration testing instead (full front-to-back end-to-end testing) using tools such as Selenium, Capybara, and Cucumber.

I hope you find this helpful. If you have more questions, let me know in the comments.

Here is a good follow-up presentation about the topic that breaks down the difference between end-to-end integration and view-JavaScript-focused testing: [BDD with JS](http://eamodeorubio.github.io/bdd-with-js)

Still, I highly recommend talking to an experienced developer in Outside-In BDD and how it breaks down the process into end-to-end integration tests (Cucumber), browser JavaScript unit tests (Jasmine), and low-level back-end unit tests (e.g. RSpec).